# What is the algorithmic complexity of a PosgtreSQL greater than or lesser than index query (compared to equality)?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, query-performance

Assuming there is an index `idx_int` on an `int_col` column, what is the algorithmic complexity of a query like this?

```
SELECT id FROM table
    WHERE table.int_col > 1;
```

I'm specifically interested in knowing if the query is significantly more inefficient than if doing an equality clause (which, if I understand correctly is O(log N)).  I am pretty sure both of them can use a B-tree, so I would expect them to be about the same in terms of complexity / efficiency.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the PostgreSQL engine, however in the real world, doing

`WHERE X > y`

will cause the engine to seek to the point in the B-tree index where `X = y`, then scan the rest of the data to return the relevant rows.  With enough data, it will take significant time to return.

Clearly, `WHERE X = y` will return more quickly since it only has to return a single row, necessitating only the initial seek operation.

This is, of course, assuming `X` is indexed.